# how to iterate list of numbers in javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a dynamic list, fetching sample data as

```js
var myStringArray = [10, 20];


var arrayLength = myStringArray.length;
for (var i = 0; i < arrayLength; i++) {
  alert(myStringArray[i]);

}
```

if I use loop it gives me data like

```
[
1
0
,
2
0
]
```

I need data as

```
10
20
```

Comment: I just reproduced your code and it's giving me just 10 and 20, as you want.

Comment: Your output suggests you actually have `var myStringArray = "[10,20]";`.

Comment: If that for loop gives you each character individually, you don't actually have an array of numbers. Do you have a JSON array instead?

Comment: @Yoshi is completely correct here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I copy and run your same code, it will give output as you want. The way you are getting it from wherever you are is giving you this data in a string i.e. "[10, 20]". So, it's not an array now, but a string with 10 characters ( [, 1, 0, ,, etc. ). That's why you get these characters when you output this in a loop.

```
var myStringArray = [10, 20];


var arrayLength = myStringArray.length;
for (var i = 0; i < arrayLength; i++) {
  alert(myStringArray[i]);

}
```

In case, you are getting this value from some resource e.g. ajax request, you can convert it to an array using `JSON.parse`, so your code becomes:

```
var myString = "[10, 20]";
var myStringArray = JSON.parse( myString );


    var arrayLength = myStringArray.length;
    for (var i = 0; i < arrayLength; i++) {
      alert(myStringArray[i]);

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The below code considers the array characters are being represented as a String. Iterate through each character. If it is an opening or closing bracket, then continue to the next iteration. A `,` represents a completed number. Otherwise concatenate the integer characters as String types:

```
var arrayLength = myStringArray.length;
var dat = "";

var arrayLength = myStringArray.length;
var dat = "";

for (var i = 0; i < arrayLength; i++) {

    if(myStringArray[i] == ","){
        alert(dat);  // alert the completed value
        dat = "";
    } else if(myStringArray[i] == "[" || myStringArray[i] == "]"){
        continue; // Move to the next iteration
    } else {
        dat += ("" + myStringArray[i]); //Concatenate strings
    }
}
```

However, your code seems to work when running the code snippet. I guess you can use my example as a visual aid as I've broken out the individual steps.

Also, as Felix Kling has pointed out in my comments, you can also use `JSON.parse()`:

```
JSON.parse(myStringArray, function(key,val) {
        console.log(val);
});
```

Here's a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/7h4z6nsm/1/

Comment: Why not just use `JSON.parse`?

Comment: @FelixKling Great point. I just wanted to break it down for the OP in the approach that he was taking by hardcoding the loop. Your method would be a lot cleaner.